# Once logged in to a webapp using excel addin, successive excel work books also opened as logged in

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have an excel VSTO project in C#, in which I can login to the webapp to load some data from web app to Excel. Once I login to the webapp using excel addin, all the successive excel workbook opened also get logged in by default.

I have a tab in GA_Ribbon and in that tab a button to loggin. Once logged all other options will be enabled in tab. Now when I open a new workbook, all the options are already enabled and it shows that the user is logged in.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Keep a list of documents they have logged in on, and set to disabled if not?

Comment: When I open a new workbook itself, it shows that the user is logged in, so am not able to disable it

Comment: Use application events such as Workbook_Open, etc. to log in and out as required, and also change the Ribbon settings accordingly?